# Magento 2 : Add to cart button "Adding" effect not work

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

my add to cart working fine but not adding effect.i had tried for searching but not found in related. if any idea plz help me.

**What i need**

[image]

**What is actual**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please add below code in your phtm file.

you have to just override addtocart.phtml file

> app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note: Make sure we have to set Yes from Store->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Shopping Cart->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart to Yes. Then it will work.

That it!!!

Comment: ok thanks for reply Bhavesh,  Will check & let you know soon.

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it. So it will help other in community as well.

Comment: dear bhavesh, i don't want to redirect to checkout page when i add to card product. your code work but one issue create, 
1. add to card message not appear properly.

Comment: @Gaurav can you please share your screenshot url for reference so I will checking and help to you

Comment: thanks for reply Bhavesh and give me some time. i am also working on same. may be third party module issue. if not resolved i will let you know.

Comment: hello, Bhavesh your code working fine, can you update without note:?? then i will give you green check.

Comment: @Gaurav note for other users help full if any stuck so required. It's working fine for you then Good sound!!

Comment: ok, i have no issues.

Comment: @Gaurav thanks for the green mark and most welcome for any issues

Comment: yup! thankyou too for help me.